# I have installed FFMPEG and can't find it inside a PHP script

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, centos, ffmpeg-php

I have installed FFMPeg in CentOS. It works perfectly.
It's inside /usr/bin directory. Also, I have PHP 7.2.24 that comes with Plesk 18.0.20.

I want to use FFMPeg inside a PHP script, but that script can't find the executable of FFMpeg. I have tried giving the exact route (/usr/bin/ffmpeg) but doesn't work.

It's a production server. The same script, in my development server (macOS) works perfectly.

I tried using:

```php
var_dump(getenv('PATH'));
var_dump(exec('which ffmpeg'));
var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir'));
var_dump(is_file(exec('which ffmpeg')));
var_dump(is_executable(exec('which ffmpeg')));
```

And it returns me:

```
string(49) "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
string(0) ""
string(44) "/var/www/vhosts/name-of-the-domain.com/:/tmp/"
bool(false)
bool(false)
NULL
```

¿What could be happening?

A very strange thing I've noticed is that I can't access any command via php:
I tried using it with echo

```php
var_dump(exec('which echo'));
var_dump(is_file(exec('which echo')));
var_dump(is_executable(exec('which echo')));
```

And it returns me:

```
string(0) ""
bool(false)
bool(false)
NULL
```

And the permissions are right:

```sh
[root@vps bin]# ls -lha echo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 33K ago 20 08:25 echo

[root@vps bin]# ls -lha ffmpeg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 217K abr  4  2019 ffmpeg
```

But if I make a

```php
var_dump(exec('echo "HELLO"'))
```

it returns me

```php
string(5) "HELLO"
```

Comment: *"I have tried giving the exact route (/usr/bin/ffmpeg) but doesn't work."* What happens exactly? What are the errors?

Comment: I'm using PHP-FFMPeg (https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) and returns me this error: "FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException: Unable to load FFMpeg"

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the PHP Extension [Suhosin](https://github.com/sektioneins/suhosin7) (using [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)) or [Security enhanced Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) (using [sestatus](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sestatus)) are installed on your server.

Suhosin has a feature to blacklist functions and SELinux might forbid execution because of mismatching file contexts.

Comment: Thanks, but Suhoshin extension isn't installed and sestatus is disabled

Comment: OK.  Then maybe your webserver (apache?) runs chrooted?  Check the output of "mount" for bind mounts and the webserver config.

Comment: You could post the ouput of phpinfo somewhere, so we can check.

Answer (score -1):

I think to use FFMPFG with php, the fastest way is to use PHP-FFMPEG package. https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg 
The issue seems to be related to permissions to execute I think.

Can you try to test it to check if the FFMPEG was loaded? Maybe PHP extension might not be loaded on your server.

Try adding this code to test if ffmpeg is loaded

```
<?php if (! extension_loaded (ffmpeg)) exit ('ffmpeg was not loaded ');
```

Comment: Thanks. What I didn't say is that I'm not using ffmpeg extension. I'm using PHP-FFMPeg (https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg), as you said. And it returns me the error "FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException: Unable to load FFMPeg".  Also extension_loaded(ffmpeg) returns me "false"

Comment: Permissions are OK also: everybody can execute ffmpeg

Comment: A very strange thing I've noticed is that I can't access any command via php: I tried using it with echo (Please see my edited post before)